# JDBC Delete Works Slow

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am having performance problem in **JDBC** Delete statement on sql server.
The table Config contains about 7 million rows, table details:

**Columns:**

1. TERMINAL_ID (varchar(50))
2. ATTRIBUTE(varchar(50))
3. VALUE (nvarchar(1000))

**Index:**
Clustered Unique Index On **TERMINAL_ID** AND **ATTRIBUTE**

The Code Looks like this, where attributes length is 1500 and this program needs about 1 hour to complete, which is very slow for delete:

```
     PreparedStatement statement = null;
     String sql = "DELETE FROM Config WHERE TERMINAL_ID = ? AND ATTRIBUTE = ?");
     for (String attribute : attributes) {
            if (statement == null) {
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
            }
            statement.setString(1, terminalId);
            statement.setString(2, attribute);
            statement.executeUpdate();
      }
```

When I run this query for 1500 times in Management Studio It needs just seconds to delete. Execution Plan looks like this:
[image]
The Problem goes off when the number of rows is small.

**The Problem goes off when I use createStatement instead of prepareStatement.**

Any Idea ?

Comment: Do you have any index on you colums ?

Comment: Are you doing this in a single transaction?

Comment: @PouriyaZarbafian I have mentiond Clusted Index in my post

Comment: @Kayaman As I Know it works in single transaction

Comment: @DavidLekishvili As you know? Do you set autocommit off in your connection?

Comment: How many attributes are you trying to delete in Java? Have you run the query in Management Studio 1500 times with the same arguments, or with 1500 pairs of different ones?

Comment: @user3707125 I tried it with different pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem and solved it. The problem was in the method **preparedStatement.setString()**, which was generating different query and the execution plan was different.

I opened SQL Server Activity Monitor where was running the query

**DELETE FROM Config WHERE TERMINAL_ID = @P0 AND ATTRIBUTE = @P1**
[image]

So I right clicked on the query and opened the execution plan which looks like:

[image]

As I guessed SQL Server was calling CONVERT_IMPLICIT function for every rows and was scanning in clustered index. This software is Third party so I had to change column to nvarchar and problem has gone.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `preparedStatement.addBatch()` this may improve performance,

```
 PreparedStatement statement = null;
 String sql = "DELETE FROM Config WHERE TERMINAL_ID = ? AND ATTRIBUTE = ?");
     for (String attribute : attributes) {
            if (statement == null) {
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
            }
            statement.setString(1, terminalId);
            statement.setString(2, attribute);
            statement.addBatch();
      }
statement.executeBatch();
//commit
```

Comment: You have one network round trip per loop iteration.  I'm sure that the time spent is network traffic.  Batching will indeed help.  Profile to find out where the time is spent.  Don't guess

Comment: I tried to run this code, Also added connection.setAutoCommit(false) before loop and statement.executeBatch(); connection.commit(); after loop. But it still works slow

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into a similar issue with very slow DELETE performance through JDBC.

The operation was simple enough: DELETE FROM t WHERE id=?

The id field was the primary key.

However, I noticed in perfmon that the delete operations were triggering full scans.

As I understand it, the underlying problem was that the column was varchar not nvarchar and the JDBC driver was rewriting the delete to do an implicit conversion of id during the query rather than converting the literal value.

This conversion prevented the query from using the index.

When I switched the column to use nvarchar the problem went away.

[Character data type conversion when using SQL Server JDBC drivers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2010/04/05/character-data-type-conversion-when-using-sql-server-jdbc-drivers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable autocommit for this connection, and then commit manually after all of your delete statements are done:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
String sql = "DELETE FROM Config WHERE TERMINAL_ID = ? AND ATTRIBUTE = ?");
try {
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    for (String attribute : attributes) {
        if (statement == null) {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
        }
        statement.setString(1, terminalId);
        statement.setString(2, attribute);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    connection.commit();
} finally {
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

I've omitted exception handling for brevity. See the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for a more elaborate example.

Answer (score 0):

Move the prepareStatement outside the loop.

```
 String sql = "DELETE FROM Config WHERE TERMINAL_ID = ? AND ATTRIBUTE = ?");
 PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);

 for (String attribute : attributes) {
        statement.setString(1, terminalId);
        statement.setString(2, attribute);
        statement.executeUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: As you see prepare Statement happens only once, because I have check for null.

Comment: @DavidLekishvili Sorry, too early in the morning for this... You need to start doing some timing in the code and see where it's getting stuck.  Some basic print's along with the current time.  You need to eliminate each step.  Is the connection taking 10 seconds and the deletes taking a second?  There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've written, so you need to pinpoint where the issue lies.  If it's in the database, maybe clear the cache (bad query plan eliminating the use of the index?)

Comment: @DavidLekishvili The last obvious thing to do would be to put the delete in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure with the correct values.  That would eliminate a bad query plan and you should see consistent performance from both the SSMS client and your JDBC client.

Comment: It seams there is problem with preparedStatement, because with createStatement it works as it should work, in seconds.